# Restart MySQL on Solaris

Tags: mysql, solaris

All,

I am trying to setup remote access for MySQL on a solaris machine. I copied my-small.cnf to /etc/my.cnf.

How do I restart MySQL in Solaris?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Search for the appropriate FMRI :

```
antoine@opensolaris:~# svcs mysql
STATE          STIME    FMRI
online         May_21   svc:/application/database/mysql:version_50
```

Restart the service in question :

```
svcadm restart mysql:version_5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. /etc/init.d mysql restart
2. svcadm restart mysql

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried svcadm.

svcadm: Pattern 'mysql' doesn't match any instances